# How to implement Content Experiments Without Redirects in a template used by many pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm setting up A/B testing using [Google Analytics Content Experiments Without Redirects (Browser-only implementation)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side) and the tests will be applied in product pages which use a single Django template. The pages are rendered using standard `render(request, template.html)`.

The problem is that apparently the experiments are per-page, so for each page that will be tested, a new experiment has to be created. Is that correct?

If yes, is there a workaround when using a single template (it includes the same `<script>` in all pages, so the experiment code would be replicated in all the pages that use the template, possibly causing issues with the analytics tracking)?
There are so many pages using that template, it would be difficult to create an experiment for each one.